# MAC OS get monitor vertical sync and horz display rate

Tags: macos, command

I need to get the vertical sync rate and horizontal scan rate of a customized LCD monitor connected to a mac mini. On Linux I know "ddcprobe" retrieves those hardware information. How can I get those info on mac? The monitor is connected to a mac mini via HDMI cable if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's [Quartz Display Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html)'s `CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode`. You can get the refresh rate using `CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate` from the returned opaque type. I don't believe there's a way to retrieve the horizontal rate.